# Is it possible to call Swing Listener's methods remotely via RMI or with other networking technology?

Tags: java, swing, implementation, rmi

These methods belongs to ActionListener and PropertyChangeListener. i need to realize these two cases and similar with other swing classes.

the server should call this method for each client, when ever some change occur in model:

```
 public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        for (AbstractViewPanel view: registeredViews) {
            view.modelPropertyChange(evt);
        }
    }
```

in case of an event on one client, each client actionPerformed() should be called from server:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  {
}
```

any help really appreciated,

jibbylala

Answer (score 1):

Since you hooked an action listener when a user clicks on a button, you can just refactor your action code to a separate method. Then your RMI client interface just calls that method.

It is called the Delegation Pattern.

Comment: what about propagation from server to other clients, means how other clients will get the updates about the occurrence of this event ("button pressed"),(not this string but real button presses)

Comment: Same thing, since your using RMI, you have to design your system in a way to support pagination. For example, total pages, offset, number items per page, etc ... If your RMI returns such information then your logic will deal with the pagination. (every request to a different page will do a round robin, a trip to the server and back to the client). RMI is just an interface, your application decides what services you need.

Comment: pagination, pages, offset, number items per page... sorry,  i m not getting you it's out of context for me. please keep in context.

Comment: Well, research about pagination, and you will understand what I just said. Your application (Client side) and (server side) should respect an API that you "create" use the delgation pattern to do what you want to.